# Why the elements in Array field are empty? It's about Simple-Schema usage in MeteorJs

Tags: arrays, meteor, simple-schema

What got me confused is described bellow.

I defined a schema named ***SomeSchema***.

```
SomeSchema=new SimpleSchema({
    content:{
        type:[Object]
    }
});
```

Then I defined a collection named ***Some***, and attach this collection to ***SomeSchema***.

```
Some=new Meteor.Collection('some');
Some.attachSchema(SomeSchema);
```

Finally, I try inserting a document into ***Some***.

```
Some.insert({content:[{a:0,b:'hello',c:true}]});
```

No error ocurrs. But the value of ***content*** is an array with an empty elment which is ***{}*** but not ***{a:0,b:'hello',c:true}***.

Can anyone tell me why?

***If I don't attach the schema, this problem won't come up.***

Answer (score 0):

I think you should declare schema like this:
`

```
SomeSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  content:{
    type:[Object],
    blackbox: true
  }
});
```

`

Comment: Thanks.    Will it be OK if I define another schema, and use it as the type of element in array?